# std::optional не может найти в namespace'е std

Tags: c++, visual-c++

на самом простом поймал ошибки, при объявлении std::optional ругается на отсутствие члена optional в пространстве имен. В чем может быть проблема

```
#include <optional>
int main()
{
    std::optional<char> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы описываете "магическое" поведение, которое невозможно объяснить. Скорее всего, вы что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: @AnT мне просто необходимо инициализировать пустую переменную типа std::optional, в коде написано то как оно делается (подглядел в хабре). Но моя среда говорит нету члена optional в пространстве имен std. И тут даже не ошибка кода, возможно это я словил баг рабочей среды либо я делаю что то не так. Как на стаке в 2016 году задал вопрос, но там была проблема у него в инклюде и сам optional находился в experimental. Сейчас вроде он в std, а может патчами перенесли в другое пространство имен.

Comment: Скорее всего вы просто не перевели свой компилятор в режим C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобная ошибка выдается Visual Studio 2017 если в установках проекта не выбран режим C++17 (`/std:c++17`). При этом в окне `Output` она сопровождается сообщением

```
class template optional is only available with C++17 or later.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подозреваю, что вы разглядываете ошибки компиляции в этом "новом" странном GUI-шном окне `Errors`, вместо того, чтобы пойти в нормальное человеческое окно `Output` и посмотреть полный вывод компилятора там. По этой причине вы и не увидели вышеупомянутого сообщения.

Comment: Окно `Errors` трудно назвать новым - оно точно есть в студии 2008, а появилось оно, если не ошибаюсь, в студии 2005. Там оно, кстати, реально полезно, в отличие от 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Две наиболее распространенные причины этого сообщения компилятора могут быть.

Первая причина - компилятор не поддерживает `std::optional`.

Вторая причина - вы не включили заголовок `<optional>`.

Еще может быть, что вы включили этот заголовок в Visual Studio перед заголовком `stdafx.h`.

Comment: 1) используется visual studio 17  2) include <optional> в проекте присутствует

Comment: @Plasmat1x Тогда приведите минимальный, готовый к компиляции код,демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: не использую предкомпилированные заголовки, компилятор на инклюд не ругается но при попытке создать переменную с типом std::optional он начинает ругаться,  при вводе std:: в контекстном меню нету члена optional

Comment: @Plasmat1x А при собственно компиляции ошибка есть? Или это проблема только с intellisense?

Comment: @Plasmat1x Это может быть просто ошибка среды, то есть в контекстном меню.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat при сборке ошибки есть

Comment: @Plasmat1x  Значит не во все файлы включили этот заголовок.

Comment: @Plasmat1x VC++ 2017, компиляция без проблем.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow один файл используется

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в шапке вопроса посмотри