# std::optional VS19

Tags: c++, optional

```
static std::optional<int> ProcessMessages() noexcept;
```

> ошибка : E0135 namespcae "std" не содержит "optional".

В коде всё работало нормально на старом пк. Сейчас поставил новый с VS19, и на нём такая ошибка вылезла. `std::optional` вообще не работает.
( `#include <optional>` выполнил)

Comment: Поставьте С++17 в настройках проекта. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964547/stdoptional-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-namespace%D0%B5-std